# Me gustaría repetir en bucle la vida de una Activity cuando tengo la pantalla del smartphone apagada

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aplicación-movil

Hola soy nueva en esto del android studios y estoy programando una app que cuando escucha un ruido la app se activa y suena un audio, al acabar el audio la aplicación vuelve a activarse y de nuevo cuando suena un ruido la app se activa y vuelve a sonar. Esto lo hace correctamente con la pantalla encendida pero si bloqueo la pantalla la aplicación una vez que se activa y suena el audio ya no se vuelve a activarse sola necesito encender la pantalla para que vuelva a activarse. Por favor alguien sabría como hacer que este proceso se haga en bucle aunq tenga la pantalla bloqueada. Muchas gracias.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        mActivateBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


        mSensor = new DetectNoise();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "NoiseAlert");


        // esto es para mostrar los elementos en el spinner de sensibilidad
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arraylistSensibilidad);
        spinnerSensibilidad.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);




                if (mRunning) {

                    mActivateBtn.setText("Desactivar");
                }


        }






        @Override
        public void onClick (View view){
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnActivate:
                    initializeApplicationConstants();
                    if (countDownTimer != null) {
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                    }
                    if (!mRunning) {
                        mRunning = true;
                        if (mp != null) {
                            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                                mp.stop();
                                mp.reset();
                            }
                            mp = null;
                        }
                        start();





                        mActivateBtn.setText("Desactivar");

                    } else if (mRunning) {
                        mActivateBtn.setText("Activar");
                        stop();





                        if (mp != null) {
                            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                                mp.stop();
                                mp.reset();
                            }
                            mp = null;
                        }

                    }
                    break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume () {

            super.onResume();


        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroy () {

            super.onDestroy();
            stop();
        }

        private void start () {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                        RECORD_AUDIO);
            }

            //Log.i("Noise", "==== start ===");
            mSensor.start();
            if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                mWakeLock.acquire();
            }
            //Noise monitoring start
            // Runnable(mPollTask) will execute after POLL_INTERVAL
            mHandler.postDelayed(mPollTask, POLL_INTERVAL);
        }

        private void stop () {
            Log.d("Noise", "==== Stop Noise Monitoring===");
            if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                mWakeLock.release();

            }

            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mSleepTask);
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mPollTask);
            //poner aqui star() y en vez de false true
            mSensor.stop();
            mRunning = false;
            mActivateBtn.setText("Activar");


        }


        private void initializeApplicationConstants () {
            // Set Noise Threshold
            mThreshold = 12;
        }

        private void updateDisplay (String status,double signalEMA){



        }

        private void callForHelp ( double signalEMA){
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            int index = PreferenceUtils.getInstance(context).getIntValue(Constants.SOUND_KEY, 0);
            if (index == 12) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(Constants.getsound(getContext()).get(index).getUri()));
            } else {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, Constants.getsound(getContext()).get(index).getPath());
            }

            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);
            stop();

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(s1 * 60000, 10000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    mActivateBtn.performClick();
                }

            }.start();




        }
```

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, eso entra en los estados de tu app, no se si era en el onStop o en el onPause donde se realiza esa acción que quieres

Answer (score 2):

Eso que quieres hacer no es posible desde una Actividad(Activity), ya que cuando se apaga o te sales de la app, entra en modo pausa, Eso podria se posible con el uso de un [Servio](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es-419)
que este en primer plano y sea visible por el usuario por medio de una notificacion o sino el el sistema android matara el Servicio(Service)...
Espero que esas referencias te guien por buen camino.